# How to use Django's CSRF protection in axios for different host?

Tags: django, reactjs, axios, csrf

I am working on ReactJS project as frontend and Django as backend and having trouble with CSRF protection!

I am using Django CORS headers and I have done all set up correctly. It works as long as I have localhost to access both front and back ends. My frontend is running on localhost:3006 and backend us running on localhost:8899 port. So frontend is setting `csrftoken` cookie and sending it with post request.

I am using `axios.create()` with `withCredentials = true` and it works fine. Now when my co-worker is running same frontend code from his system, trying to connect to backend that is running on my machine, he is getting 403 csrf cookie not found! At this time, he is running his frontend on `localhost:3006`, his own localhost and connecting to backend of `my-ip:8899`. So I believe that we would have this problem too on production when we will have `www.example.com` serving frontend and `api.example.com` serving backend as cookies of frontend host wont get sent to api host!

My cors header settings in django,

```
# Origin white list
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost',
    'http://127.0.0.1',
    'http://192.168.1.165',
    'http://192.168.1.165:3006',
]

CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = (
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',
)

# Allowed methods
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
)

# Allowed headers
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'X-tz',
    'x-tz',
    'x-requested-with',
)

# # CSRF COOKIE NAME
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "csrftoken"

# To allow default credentials
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

and my Axios create code is,

```
let tz = "UTC";

try {
    tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
} catch (e) {
    consoleError(e);
}

const API = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST,
    timeout: 30000,
    withCredentials: true,
    xsrfCookieName: CSRF_COOKIE_NAME,
    xsrfHeaderName: "X-CSRFToken",
    headers: {'X-tz': tz}
});
```

So as I said, if I am connecting from my machine to my machine using localhost/IP and ports, it works but when my co-worker is trying to connect from his localhost/IP frontend to my ip-backend it doesn't allow him to make POST request without CSRF cookie! I don't want to bypass Django security of CSRF with decorator. So can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Set `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` to your eTLD+1 domain, so that the cookie is also sent to subdomains. By default the csrf cookie will have just your www.domain.com, but if you set it to domain.com, your axios request will pick it up and send it to api.domain.com.

Comment: Just to explain: CSRF works by matching the token in the cookie to the token in the X-CSRFToken header (or in the form data). Your axios request must sent **both**. Since no one but your website can set the cookies for your domain and a browser will never send a cookie cross-domain, this works.

Comment: Good question by the way, your problem was well explained. Deserves upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSRF works by matching the token in the cookie to the token in the X-CSRFToken header (or in the form data). Your axios request must sent **both**.

It's sending the token in the X-CSRFToken. But it's not sending the cookie to api.yourhost.com because the cookie was set for the domain www.yourhost.com. That's the default in Django.

Change `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` to your eTLD+1 domain preceded by a `.`, i.e. .yourhost.com, so that it's sent to every of your subdomains, including api.yourhost.com.

Now in your test scenario, this cannot work, because the cookie set by your coworker's frontend is for localhost whereas the axios request is to your ip. There's no solution for this except have your co-worker get the frontend also from your ip.

Comment: very well explained information! Thanks for the answer. I am going to wait a little while to see if someone else answers! I couldn't upvote but I will accept it as answer if no one else adds answer.

Comment: thanks for the very clear explanation. Until now I thought the csrf header and the csrf cookie were two names for the same thing. Thanks to you I finally managed to get a 200 response